# Performance comparison between < and Source in MySql Cli

Tags: mysql, performance, command-line-interface

I am executing my large MySql script of size 12GB. I am using the following command

1. mysql -host=localhost -user=temp -password=temp
2. use mydb
3. Source c:/script.sql

It is taking so much time. there is one of my colleagues mentioned that not using "Source" and using the following MySQL command can perform faster.

1. mysql -host=localhost -user=temp -password=temp mydb < c:/script.sql

I am unable to understand the logic. I need help in this regard.

Thanks

Comment: What's to understand? It's just the way MySQL works, there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @Barmar, I want to know if there is really a performance difference between both commands?

Comment: Run a test and find out. Easy way to see if this is folklore or fact.

Comment: I misunderstood what you wrote, I thought you already confirmed that it was faster.

Comment: Bug?  Check slash in second version.

Answer (score 1):

Using source will cause you to get a lot of output about the success of the queries.  Redirecting stdin suppresses that; using source, you can also suppress that with the --silent command line option, but that will also affect how query results are shown (though redirecting from stdin will also affect how query results are shown).

There should be no actual performance difference on the server side, but flooding your terminal with output can slow down requests being sent to the server.